# Как решить ошибку с Macro?

Tags: android-studio

я уже третий день не могу найти ответа как решить данную ошибку связанная с файлом values.xml, в ютубе говорят что это изза версии material и на форумах с сайтами тоже, я уже всё перепробовал:
1 переустанавливать в разные диски студию и sdk
2 менять версии андроид студио
3 менять версии appcomat, material
4 менял версии sdk

версия андроид 2020.3.1 artic fox

в итоге постоянная ошибка: Can't determine type for tag

```
Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'
```